# Add Cancel Button to Form, bypassing Validation in Vue.js

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

I have a modal window which has a form that is used to register a new user. Both fields on the form are required. Upon clicking submit, the registration function is called.

```
 <form v-on:submit='registration'>
   <input type="text" name="email" required="required" /><br>
   <input type="text" name="userName" required="required" /><br>
   <input type='submit' name="register" value='Register' />
 </form>
```

I would like to add a "cancel" button to the form so that users can cancel if they do not wish to register. I have tried adding the following:

```
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="window.location.href='http://localhost:8088'" />
```

But this is not working. How can I add a cancel button that can be triggered, closing the modal widow, and bypassing the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following and this worked:

```
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" v-on:click="closeModal" />
```

J